# How to set comma separate values to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

```
method1('id','name')
```

This is the method I called.

```
Array.prototype.method1 = function (property) {

  console.log(property)  //Expect ['id','name']
)
```

I want to get result like ['id','name']

```
const property = property.split(",");
console.log(property)    //This shows only ['id']
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: `function (...properties) { console.log(properties); }`

Comment: Than you very much its working

Comment: FYI, adding properties to the Array prototype is a very bad thing to do.  Besides the conceptual issues about adding methods to a standard prototype, it also disables a bunch of interpreter optimizations, making some array operations a LOT slower.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try two ways :

```js
 function check() {
   console.log([...arguments])
 }

check(1,2,"apple")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Will output what you're expecting, but not sure that JS experts would write code like this.

```
var s = "id,name";
var a =  s.split(",");

Array.prototype.method1 = function(property) {
  console.log(property);  //Expect ['id','name']
}
a.method1(a);    //this will display your expected
```